# [Oracle][ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver]Cannot load client certificate

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

I am configuring a goldengate replication from on-prem oracle database to gcp cloudsql postgres .

i have completed firewall and client certificate generation with SSL enabled .

connecting to cloudsql from onprem server using psql works fine .

but connect to the cloudsql db from goldengate client fails  with below error

GGSCI (server) 1> dblogin sourcedb dbname useridalias dbname

2023-07-26 03:30:53  WARNING OGG-00552  Database operation failed: Couldn't connect to dbname. ODBC error: SQLSTATE 28000 native database error 0. [Oracle][ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver]Cannot load client certificate.
Error: Database operation failed: Couldn't connect to dbname. ODBC error: SQLSTATE 28000 native database error 0. [Oracle][ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver]Cannot load client certificateFailed to open data source dbname for user ggadmin

Please share a solution for :
[Oracle][ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver]Cannot load client certificate